# Eloquent query fails without error if result is not limited

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I passed my project from localhost to live server 4 days ago and still trying to find the cause for my problem.

Some of my queries fail without returning any error. Little investigation showed that this happens with queries returning thousands of rows as a result

Query

```
Store::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=','stores.user_id')->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')->get(['stores.*','users.name']);
```

fails, while

```
Store::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=','stores.user_id')->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')->limit(4000)->get(['stores.*','users.name']);
```

is working.

Writing the query in phpMyAdmin is also working fine.

Laravel version 5.5., mysql version 10.2.31
Thanks